# Open files from array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I wrote a code where I want a user to select multiple files that code will loop through.

I can't get the loop to work as I am not defining the name right.

```
Sub RFPDataimporttest() 'select multiple files
    Dim Files As Workbook
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
    Dim DestWbk As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer

    Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook
    'choose files and define them as array
    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select alla RFP filer från leverantörer", MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(Fname) Then
        For i = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)

            'this where i have a problem. how do i open each file in an array?
            Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)

            SrcWbk.Sheets("1. General Information").Range("L8").Copy
            With DestWbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(-1, 1)
               .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
               .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With

            SrcWbk.Sheets("2. Product information").Range("Z1:AB91").Copy
            With DestWbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With

            SrcWbk.Close False

        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is an array - you are already checking that and looping over it. Simply use `i` as index:

```
  Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname(i))
```

(note that the result is even an array when user selects only one file, so code will work for that case also)